# Weak convergence of probability measures on [0,1]

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $0 < M < \infty$ and let $f,f_1,f_2,\ldots : [0,1]\rightarrow [0,M]$ be Borel-measurable functions with $\int_0^1 f d\lambda = \int_0^1 f_n d\lambda = 1$. Suppose $\lim_n f_n(x) = f(x)$ for each fixed $x \in [0,1]$. Define probability measures $\mu, \mu_1, \mu_2, \dots $ by $\mu(A) = \int_A f d\lambda$ and $\mu_n(A) = \int_A f_n d\lambda$ for Borel $A\subseteq[0,1]$. Prove that $\mu_n \Rightarrow \mu$.

My first attempt was to use the equivalent criterion:

- $\mu_n(A) \rightarrow \mu(A)$ for all measurable sets $A$ such that $\mu(\partial A)=0$ where $\partial A$  denotes the boundary of $A$.

Let $A\subseteq [0,1]$ be a Borel set such that $\mu(\partial A)=0$. Then we have

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mu_n(A) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_A f_n d\lambda = \int_A \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  f_n d\lambda = \int_A   f d\lambda = \mu(A)  $$

Where I have applied Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem in the second equality.

Is this approach to the problem correct? Can anyone help in making the argument above more clear?

I also feel I could use Skorohod's Theorem but I didn't get very far. Suggestions for other approaches are very welcome. For example, is it feasible to use the definition of weak convergence directly?

Comment: Your proof using DCT is fine if $\lambda$ is supposed to be the Lebesgue measure (or an other finite measure). Why do you doubt this?

Comment: Thanks. Yes $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. I guess I was unsure because I haven't had a lot of exposure to measure theory.